# infinite loop, LeetCode 1721

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

here's my code :

```
class Solution {
    public int size (ListNode head)
    {
        int size = 0;
        ListNode curr = head;
        while (curr != null)
        {
            size ++;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        return size;
    }
    public ListNode swapNodes(ListNode head, int k) {
        ListNode curr = head;
        ListNode curr2 = head;
        ListNode pre = null;
        ListNode pre2 = null;
        ListNode result = head;
        for (int i = 1; i < k && curr != null; i ++)
        {
            pre = curr;
            curr = curr.next;
        }
        int size = size(head);
        for (int i = 0; i < (size - k) && curr2 != null; i ++)
        {
            pre2 = curr2;
            curr2 = curr2.next;
        }
        ListNode tmp = curr.next;
        ListNode tmp2 = curr2.next;
        pre.next = curr2;
        curr2.next = tmp;
        pre2.next = curr;
        curr.next = tmp2;
        return head;
        
    }
}
```

there seems to be an infinite loop in one of the cases and i can't fix it, can someone help please ?

Comment: please provide more information. How do you call your method

Comment: Lists with loops?

Comment: @gemorra this is a method that swipes the element in the kth position from the beginning of the list, with the element in the kth position from the end of the list, you call the method by invoking it on the head of the linked list and you give it an integer "k" to determine which elements it will be swapping

Comment: @knittl yes the loops in this code are used to move the pointers to point to the nodes to be swapped

Comment: I got what it should do. I just wanted to know, how you called the method and ended up in a infinite loop. Or is it always like this? And could you point me to the Class ListNode. I can't find it?

Comment: @gemorra Definition for singly-linked list.
 ' public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * } '
and the infinite loop case happens when two pointers are pointing at the same node

Comment: @gemorra i'm sorry the code looks the way it does, it's my first time posting here so i'm still kind of new to this

Comment: You shouldn't post code in comments. You should edit the question, and add the additional information there. You can use the comments to let us know that you made such and such a change.

Answer (score 0):

for me everything works fine. Maybe you are using other inputs or initialising the List in a wrong way.

I added a method to your ListNode class to create the list in a fluent way:

```
public ListNode addListNode(int v) {
    ListNode listNode = new ListNode(v);
    next = listNode;
    return listNode;
}
```

and a print Method to your Solution class to print the list.

```
public static void printList(ListNode head)
{
    StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
    ListNode curr = head;
    while (curr != null)
    {
        out.append(curr.val).append(",");
        curr = curr.next;
    }
    System.out.println(out);
}
```

Running it with this main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ListNode listNode = new ListNode(1);
    ListNode currNode = listNode.addListNode(2);
    for( int i = 3; i <= 10; i++) {
        currNode = currNode.addListNode(i);
    }
    // you also could write listNode.addListNode(2).addListNode(3).addListNode(4) ...

    printList(listNode);
    System.out.println("SwapNodes");
    ListNode swappedListNode = swapNodes(listNode, 2);
    printList(swappedListNode);
}
```

it outputs

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
SwapNodes
1,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,2,10,
```

So it seems to work as expected, no infinite loop. As I mentioned at the beginning feel free to add your main method and the way you are calling the swapNodes Method.

You can edit your question and add these informations..